# The usage of bankruptcy and liquidation

Tags: word-usage

When I searched the difference between them on the Internet, I came across an official state site which says :

> Bankruptcy is a legal proceeding in which people who cannot pay their
>   bills can get a fresh financial start.
>
> Bankruptcy is not a legal option available for companies.
>
> A company that is unable to pay its debts as they fall due, can be
>   placed into liquidation either voluntarily or by court order.

Is this explanation correct for all countries using  English?

---

But when I looked the word bankruptcy up on Cambridge Dictionary, it says :

> a ​situation in which a ​business or a ​person ​becomes ​bankrupt: The
>   ​company was ​forced into bankruptcy. The ​toll of bankruptcies was
>   ​rising ​daily.

I know these terms involves a lot of legal processes but could you please explain the difference between them ?

For example:

- A company that went bankruptcy can pay off its debts without closing its business?
- A company that went into liquidation can pay off its debts without closing its business?

Comment: These really are legal questions; the words themselves will be defined in the relevant laws and may differ among jurisdictions.

Comment: In the US there are different types of bankruptcies with different rules regarding the requirement to close the business or not.  Regardless, the term "bankruptcy" still means that a person or business cannot/will not pay its debts and has applied for relief from its/his/her debts through the courts.

Comment: The general public (and general purpose dictionaries like Cambridge) will use *bankruptcy* far more loosely than those in legal or financial circles, just like a botanist or a chef may differ on what constitutes *fruit*, or how a traffic engineer might define *highway*. What specifically terms like *bankruptcy* and *liquidation* (and *receivership* and *reorganization* and *insolvency*) mean depends on the jurisdiction. Wikipedia lists at least [six different things called *bankruptcy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankruptcy_in_the_United_States) in the United States alone.

Comment: Note that the term "liquidation" has meanings outside of bankruptcy.  For instance, if a business owner decides to close the business he may "liquidate" it, selling all it's assets.  This even though the business was "a going concern" -- profitable and essentially debt-free -- prior to the liquidation.  And liquidation is one of the strategies that may be used to deal with bankruptcy, but it's not the only one.

Comment: BTW, _went bankruptcy_ is not correct. It's either _went bankrupt_ or _went into bankruptcy_.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Is the use of _different_ in _there are different types of bankruptcies_ correct? I thought it should be something like _there are various types of bankruptcies_ .

Answer (score 1):

Informally, *bankruptcy* is used for any person or entity.

Slightly more formally, people enter *bankruptcy*, companies go into *liquidation* (while people sometimes are *liquidated*, the meaning is entirely different).

Properly (i.e. legally), the correct terminology depends on the insolvency law in force in your jurisdiction: *receivership* of several different forms, *compulsory winding-up* (not for individuals, you will be relieved to hear), *trusteeship* and other terms all apply at different times and in different places. *Insolvency* is the best generic term, though even that has pitfalls; people can be *insolvent* for years, relying on the toleration of creditors, without any consequences. Partnerships and companies sometimes do the same, though it is most places illegal.

Just to illustrate the confusion inherent in this area: a company that is able to pay its debts without closing its business is by definition neither insolvent nor bankrupt, so that your example, though grammatical, is mistaken.